# JFrame Positioning components using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm trying to position several components using the GridBagLayout, but I'm a bit confused. When I try positioning them they don't move and just create several columns. I have tried using null layout but get punished every time.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main
{

    JFrame window = new JFrame("PE Fixture");   //JFrame variables
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    JPanel guestFixturesPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel guestFixturesTitle = new JLabel("FIXTURES");
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JSeparator southBar1 = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
    JSeparator southBar2 = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
    JTable listTable = new JTable();

    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();

    public Main()
    {

        container.setLayout(cardLayout);

        guestFixturesPanel.setLayout(layout);        //GUEST FIXTURES PANEL COMPONENTS
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            guestFixturesTitle.setBounds(120, 20, 500, 50);
            guestFixturesTitle.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50));
            guestFixturesTitle.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            guestFixturesPanel.add(guestFixturesTitle, c);
            southBar1.setBounds(0, 760, 500, 10);
            northBar1.setBounds(0, 80, 500, 10);

            listTable = new JTable(data, columns)
            {
                public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns)        //Makes cells editable false by anyone
                {
                    return false;
                }

            };
            listTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 750));
            listTable.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
            listTable.setBounds(22, 100, 450, 640);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(listTable);
            listTable.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            guestFixturesPanel.add(scroll, c);
            loginButton.setBounds(330, 770, 150, 50);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
            guestFixturesPanel.add(loginButton, c);

            container.add(guestFixturesPanel, "2");  
            cardLayout.show(container, "1");

        window.add(container);          //Creates the frame of the program.
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500, 860);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide the actual code. It would make it a lot easier to tell you where your problems are.

Comment: That should be working, I just removed all of the unnecessary code in relation to the problem

Comment: southBar1, northBar1, listTable, and loginButton are missing their declarations. The code will not compile.

Comment: Oh of course sorry, let me add them

Comment: Edited, sorry about that

Comment: I am puzzled: 1) you don't use GridBagLayout (at most a GridLayout which is a complete different animal) 2) Lot's of your code is missing to make it compile (let's not go into discussion about running that) 3) You call setBounds but put everything into containers with LayoutManager (ie, you are trying to fight against LayoutManager's). Try to make a more consistent example and start by stopping calling setBounds: just drop that poor, unhealthy and nasty habit.

Comment: The GridLayout may be my issue, how silly of me. Also the only reason I'm calling setBounds is because I had null layout before and in case the gridBagLayout didn't work then I could go back without having to do the math again.

Comment: Just forget about using the so-called "null-layout", you should always, I mean always, use a LayoutManager. There are other issues in your code but the GridLayout definitely looks like one. I am not sure of what you are trying to do, so I can't give a better answer for now. Make sure that if you answer somebody's comment you put something like "@somebody" in your comment. People don't poll your post constantly to see if you have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is here:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
...
guestFixturesPanel.setLayout(layout);
```

You're using [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) instead of [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Consequently when you add a component to `guestFixturesPanel` the layout manager is ignoring the constraint. For instance here:

```
guestFixturesPanel.add(guestFixturesTitle, c); // c is completely ignored
```

Additionaly, about this:

```
guestFixturesTitle.setBounds(120, 20, 500, 50);
```

Never-ever mix layout managers with [setBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). These are two completely incompatible things.